Sort tbody list which is populated with Javascript getList?
I have a router with a DHCP page which is not sorted by the internal IP number, instead it is fully random. I have full access to the html and javascript, and I can modify this without any issues. However I cannot figure out how to make the list sorted by IP-address by default. I have no need to be able to manually click and sort, I just want the list to always be sorted by IP-address.
I cannot figure out if it is possible to sort a getList, or if it has to be done in the randerBandlist function.
The list html:
                <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="30"></th>
                        <th><%:设备名称%></th>
                        <th><%:IP地址%></th>
                        <th><%:MAC地址%></th>
                        <th width="150" class="center"><%:操作%></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="bandlist">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="center" colspan="5"><%:查询中...%></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

This is the part that handles the list in question:
getList = function( callback ){
        $.getJSON('<%=luci.dispatcher.build_url("api", "xqnetwork","macbind_info")%>',{},function(rsp){
            if ( rsp.code != 0 ) {
                return;
            }
            callback( rsp );
        });
    },
    randerBandlist = function( rsp ){
        var tpl = $( '#tplbandlist' ).html(),
            container = $( '#bandlist' ),
            bandlistdata = rsp.list,
            tpldata = [],
            mac, ip, dname;
        currentList = {};
        if ( bandlistdata.length > 0 ) {
            for (var i = 0; i < bandlistdata.length; i++) {
                mac = bandlistdata[i].mac.toUpperCase();
                ip = bandlistdata[i].ip;
                dname = StringH.encode4Html( bandlistdata[i].name );
                tpldata.push({
                    dname: dname,
                    ip: ip,
                    mac: mac
                });
                currentList[ip] = 1;
            }
        }
        container.html( tpl.tmpl( {bandlist: tpldata} ) );
    },
return {
    init: function(){
        getList( randerBandlist );
        addEvent();
    }
}

Also included the full function, however I think the function above is the one that needs modifying:
var ModelDhcpband = (function(){
var lanIP = '<%=lanip%>',
    ipprefix = (function(ip){
        var arr = ip.split('.');
        arr.pop();
        return arr.join('.') + '.';
    })(lanIP),
    currentList = {},
    // get repeat set
    getRepeat = function( data ){
        data = data || [];
        var repeat = [];
        var _currentList = $.extend( {}, currentList);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var v = data[i];
            if ( typeof( _currentList[v] ) == 'undefined' ) {
                _currentList[v] = 1;
            } else {
                repeat.push(v);
            }
        }
        return repeat;
    },
    getList = function( callback ){
        $.getJSON('<%=luci.dispatcher.build_url("api", "xqnetwork","macbind_info")%>',{},function(rsp){
            if ( rsp.code != 0 ) {
                return;
            }
            callback( rsp );
        });
    },
    randerBandlist = function( rsp ){
        var tpl = $( '#tplbandlist' ).html(),
            container = $( '#bandlist' ),
            bandlistdata = rsp.list,
            tpldata = [],
            mac, ip, dname;
        currentList = {};
        if ( bandlistdata.length > 0 ) {
            for (var i = 0; i < bandlistdata.length; i++) {
                mac = bandlistdata[i].mac.toUpperCase();
                ip = bandlistdata[i].ip;
                dname = StringH.encode4Html( bandlistdata[i].name );
                tpldata.push({
                    dname: dname,
                    ip: ip,
                    mac: mac
                });
                currentList[ip] = 1;
            }
        }
        container.html( tpl.tmpl( {bandlist: tpldata} ) );
    },
    randerDevlist = function( rsp ){
        var tpl = $( '#tpldevlist' ).html(),
            devlistdata = rsp.devicelist,
            tpldata = [],
            randerDom,
            mac, ip, dname, tag;
        if ( devlistdata.length > 0 ) {
            for (var i = 0; i < devlistdata.length; i++) {
                mac = devlistdata[i].mac.toUpperCase();
                ip = devlistdata[i].ip;
                iplast = (function( ip ){
                    var arr = ip.split('.');
                    return arr[arr.length - 1];
                })( ip );
                dname = StringH.encode4HtmlValue( devlistdata[i].name );
                tag = devlistdata[i].tag;
                if ( tag != 2 ) {
                    tpldata.push({
                        dname: dname,
                        ip: iplast,
                        mac: mac
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        randerDom = tpl.tmpl( {
            devlist: tpldata,
            ipprefix: ipprefix
        } );
        $.dialog({
            title: '<%:绑定设备%>',
            content: randerDom,
            lock: true,
            width: 828,
            padding: '30px'
        });
        $.pub( 'done', {id: '#addlist'} );
    },
    serializeForm = function( form ){
        var ips = $( '.ip', form ),
            dnames = $( '.dname', form ),
            macs = $( '.mac', form ),
            data = [],
            item;
        ips.each(function( idx, el ){
            item = {
                ip: ipprefix + $.trim( el.value ),
                mac: $.trim( macs.eq( idx ).val() ),
                name: $.trim( dnames.eq( idx ).val() )
            };
            data.push( item );
        });

        return ObjectH.stringify( data );
    }
    unbind = function( e, mac ){
        e.preventDefault();
        var that = this,
            $this = $(that),
            requestURL = '<%=luci.dispatcher.build_url("api", "xqnetwork", "mac_unbind")%>',
            requestData = {
                mac: mac
            };
        $.pub( 'loading:start' );
        $.ajax({
            url: requestURL,
            type: 'POST',
            data: requestData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function( rsp ){
                if ( rsp.code !== 0 ) {
                    $.alert( rsp.msg );
                } else {
                    getList( randerBandlist );
                    $( '#dellist' ).hide();
                }
                $.pub( 'loading:stop' );
            }
        });
    },
    addEvent = function(){
        // unband
        $('body').delegate( '.btn-unband' ,'click', function( e ){
            var that = this,
                $this = $( that ),
                mac = $this.attr('data-mac'),
                ok = function(){
                    unbind.call( that, e, mac );
                };
            $.confirm( '<%:你确定要解除此项绑定？%>', ok );
        });
        // band
        $( 'body' ).delegate( '#addbandlist', 'submit', function( e ){
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = e.target,
                formName = form.name,
                formels = $( 'input', form ),
                requestURL = '<%=luci.dispatcher.build_url("api", "xqnetwork", "mac_bind")%>',
                requestData,
                rules,
                name,
                display,
                validator,
                formdata,
                iplist = [],
                formdata,
                formdataojb,
                repeatIP,
                validerules = [];

            validator = Valid.checkAll( $('#addbandlist')[0] );

            if ( validator) {
                formdata = serializeForm( form );
                formdataojb = StringH.evalExp( formdata );
                for (var i = 0; i < formdataojb.length; i++) {
                    iplist.push(formdataojb[i]['ip']);
                }
                repeatIP = getRepeat( iplist );
                if ( repeatIP.length !== 0 ) {
                    $.alert( '<%:存在IP冲突，请检查输入项%>' + repeatIP.join(' , ') );
                    return;
                }

                requestData = {
                    data: formdata
                };
                $.pub( 'wait', {id: '#submitbandlist'} );
                $.ajax({
                    url: requestURL,
                    data: requestData,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function( rsp ){
                        if ( rsp.code == 0 ) {
                            location.reload( 1 );
                        } else {
                            $.alert( rsp.msg );
                        }
                        $.pub( 'done', {id: '#submitbandlist'} );
                    }
                });
            }

        });

        // add a item
        $( 'body' ).delegate( '#addoneitem', 'click', function( e ){
            e.preventDefault();
            var tpl = $( '#tpldevitem' ).html(),
                form = $( '#banditems' ),
                btnSubmit = $( '#submitbandlist' ),
                lastidx = (function(){
                    if ( form.find('tr').length > 0 ) {
                        return form.find('tr:last').attr( 'data-idx' );
                    }
                    return 0;
                }()),
                lastidx = parseInt( lastidx, 10 ),
                item = tpl.tmpl({
                    idx: lastidx + 1,
                    ipprefix: ipprefix
                });
            if ( !isNaN( lastidx ) ) {
                form.append( item );
                if ( form.find( 'tr' ).length > 0 ) {
                    btnSubmit.show();
                } else {
                    btnSubmit.hide();
                }
            } else {
                $.alert('<%:出现异常，请刷新页面%>');
            }
        } );

        // del a item
        $( 'body' ).delegate( '.btn-del-item', 'click', function( e ){
            e.preventDefault();
            var tar = e.target,
                tr = $( tar ).parents( 'tr' ),
                form = $( '#banditems' ),
                btnSubmit = $( '#submitbandlist' ),
                isEmpty = (function(){
                    var empty = true;
                    tr.find('input').each(function(){
                        if ( this.value !== '') {
                            empty = false;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    return empty;
                }()),
                ok = function(){
                    tr.remove();
                    if ( form.find( 'tr' ).length > 0 ) {
                        btnSubmit.show();
                    } else {
                        btnSubmit.hide();
                    }
                };
            if ( isEmpty ) {
                ok();
            } else {
                $.confirm( '<%:确定要删除这项数据吗%>', ok );
            }
        } );

        // open add dlg
        $( '#addlist' ).click(function( e ){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.pub( 'wait', {id: '#addlist'} );
            getList( randerDevlist );
        });

        // check for del
        $( 'body' ).delegate( '.bandmac', 'click', function( e ){
            if ( $('.bandmac:checked').length > 0 ) {
                $( '#dellist' ).show();
            } else {
                $( '#dellist' ).hide();
            }
        } );

        // del all
        $( '#dellist' ).on( 'click', function( e ){
            e.preventDefault();
            if ( $('.bandmac:checked').length == 0 ) {
                $.alert( '<%:你还未选择任何设备%>' );
                return;
            }
            var that = this,
                $this = $(that),
                mac = (function(){
                    var tmp = [];
                    $('.bandmac:checked').each(function(){
                        tmp.push( this.value );
                    });
                    return tmp.join( ';' );
                }()),
                ok = function(){
                    unbind.call( that, e, mac );
                };

            $.confirm( '<%:确认要解除选中项目的绑定关系？%>', ok );
        } );
    };

currentList[lanIP] = 1;

return {
    init: function(){
        getList( randerBandlist );
        addEvent();
    }
}
}());
$(function(){
    ModelDhcpband.init();
});


As far as I understand, this is the part of your code preparing the list of objects containing the ip address before rendering:
if ( bandlistdata.length > 0 ) {
    for (var i = 0; i < bandlistdata.length; i++) {
        mac = bandlistdata[i].mac.toUpperCase();
        ip = bandlistdata[i].ip;
        dname = StringH.encode4Html( bandlistdata[i].name );
        tpldata.push({
            dname: dname,
            ip: ip,
            mac: mac
        });
        currentList[ip] = 1;
    }
}

So the route you are looking for is sorting the tpldata array before calling:
container.html( tpl.tmpl( {bandlist: tpldata} ) );

This is how you could sort the array, by calling the sort array method with a callback that will split the octets of each ip address to compare and will evalute their parts individually to determine which one comes first:


const array = [
  { ip: "192.168.1.1" },
  { ip: "10.0.0.1" },
  { ip: "192.168.1.2" },
  { ip: "172.16.0.1" }
];

array.sort((a, b) => {
  //splitting the parts of ip address held by a and b
  const aParts = a.ip.split('.').map(Number);
  const bParts = b.ip.split('.').map(Number);

  //comparing the parts of the ip address a and b to determine which comes first
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (aParts[i] !== bParts[i]) {
      return aParts[i] - bParts[i];
    }
  }

  //ips are the same
  return 0;
});

console.log(array);



So in your scenario just replace array with tpldata and call sort just before setting the container html.
